# PHP dynamic URL slugs with multiple languages

Tags: php, internationalization, url-routing, slug, slugify

I am trying to create PHP pages with SEO-friendly slugs like so:

```
www.example.com/italian-foods
www.example.com/de/italienisches-essen
www.example.com/it/cibo-italiano
```

Links are created with [php-i18n](https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n) and [slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) like so:

```
<?php
    $link = $i18n->getAppliedLang() .'/'. $slugify->slugify(L::menu_italianfoods);
?>

<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
    <?php echo L::menu_italianfoods; ?>
</a>
```

This allows dynamic creation of the slug in each language based simply on the translated string for `menu_italianfoods`.

If the links were not slugified, the links would lead to `index.php?page=italian-foods` where `index.php` includes the actual file based on `$_GET['page']`, in this case `views/italian-foods.php`.

What is the recommended best-practice for "de-slugifying" the URL in this example? I can imagine a script which switches all possible slugs and points to the correct file to include, but I am not sure if this is overly complicated. Is there a better approach?